# How to extract multiple floats on separate lines from output in shell?

Tags: bash

I need to extract the float values from a multiple line output with multiple floats from a speedtest-cli shell output, using bash. I will then assign them to a variable.

Some example output:

```
Ping: 13.25ms
Download: 37.66Mbps
Upload: 5.03Mbps
```

How would I best do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the floats and put them in an array:

```
numbers=( $(speedtest-cli ... | grep -Eo '\b[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?') )
```

- `grep -Eo '\b[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?'` gets the floats from the output of `speedtest-cli`
- `numbers` is an array containing the floats, now you can manipulate the array elements using usual array operations

Comment: And rather than storing them in an array, how would I store the output in separate variables?

Comment: @Pelts `bash` (indexed) arrays are zero-indexed, you can get the first element by `${numbers[0]}`, second by `${numbers[1]}` and so on. If you need to explicitly use variables, i would suggest you to assign array values as the values of such variables, without changing the current flow.